# Javascript reruning timeout after being cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout

I have a function with parameters  that do some operations on these parameters then send them to itself again with certain timeout
Now i want to clear this timeout but at some point i want to recall that timeout that was cleared with its current parameters anyway to do this ?

```
var thread
$(document).ready(function(){
    f(0, 0)

    $('.pause').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(thread);
    });

    $('.resume').click(function(){
        thread; //want to rerun thread
    });

    f(x, y) {
        thread = setTimeout(function(){
            f(x + 1, y + 1);
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `f(0, 0)` again in the `resume` click handler:

```
$('.resume').click(function(){
    f(0, 0);
});
```

If you want to continue on from where the `x` and `y` values were paused, you need to store them first. Try this:

```
var thread;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var publicX, publicY; 

    f(0, 0);

    $('.pause').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(thread);
    });

    $('.resume').click(function(){
        f(publicX, publicY);
    });

    function f(x, y) {
        publicX = x;
        publicY = y;            
        thread = setTimeout(function(){
            f(++publicX, ++publicY);
        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1094pcyc/)

Note that because the `publicX` and `publicY` variables are now within the scope of all handlers you no longer need to include them as arguments of the `f()` function. I've left them in in this example in case you have some other logic which requires their use.

Comment: but i dont want to begin with zeros again i want the x and y that it stopped at

Comment: there is no way to get x and y from the thread like for example thread.get(param1) ?

Comment: No. The thread variable only contains the id of the timer. There is no way it can retrieve any value from the anonymous function within the timer itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thread;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    f(x, y)

    $('.pause').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(thread);
    });

    $('.resume').click(function(){
        f(x,y); //want to rerun thread
    });

    f(x, y) {
        thread = setTimeout(function(){
            f(x + 1, y + 1);
        }, 1000)
    }
```